# Verbo più specifico di fare per "fare uno scherzo"

Tags: word-choice

In *fare uno scherzo* il verbo *fare* mi sembra abbastanza generico.

È corretto, di certo, e suona anche bene, ma mi cheidevo se l'italiano fosse fornito di un verbo meno generico e più appropriato a questo contesto.

Ho come l'impressione di aver sentito/letto (e cercare su Google sembra confermare che non mi sbaglio) la costruzione *tirare uno scherzo*.

Ci sono altri verbi adatti allo scopo?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao! le espressioni "tirare uno scherzo", o "giocare uno scherzo" si adoperano solitamente in accezione negativa, "mi ha tirato/giocato un brutto scherzo". A volte la parola scherzo si combina anche con l'aggettivo bello, "che bello scherzo mi hai giocato!", in chiave ironico-sarcastica. Credo però che non ci sia nulla da obiettare se si vuole usare la combinazione "tirare uno scherzo" anche in una frase affermativa: "E' Carnevale, oggi voglio tirare uno scherzo a qualcuno". Sbagliato non suona ;)

Comment: In questo sito si cerca di corroborare le proprie risposte con fonti. Aggiungi qualche dizionario o autore famoso in cui compaiono le espressioni che dici, per piacere? Per esempio, a me personalmente (romano) “tirare uno scherzo” non suona affatto familiare, e non lo trovo sui dizionari: è possibile che sia un uso regionale. Aggiungo che sembra un calco dall'inglese (_to pull a prank, a trick_).

Comment: Per la verità a me 'tirare uno scherzo' è familiare e non credo sia regionale. Ad esempio c'è la citazione in  https://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Libera?q=scherzo&page=14&as=1   Accademia della crusca- Grande dizionario della lingua italiana. UTET. E l'ho trovato in altri contesti. E anche in dizionari iialiano-inglese come Reverso, molti esempi,  o quello del Corriere della Sera. A me suona un po' da lingua scritta, come 'giocare' uno scherzo, nel parlato vedo 'fare'. Ma 'fare' è anche da lingua scritta, perfettamente, ho visto esempio di Leopardi. Ma effettivamente ci possono essere usi locali.

Comment: Le osservazioni di Arianna Bonvicin mi sembrano giuste, certo ci vorrebbe qualche 'pezza di appoggio',  per completare la risposta.

Comment: Grazie mille, @BakerStreet! Il GDLI effettivamente registra “tirare un brutto, cattivo scherzo” (quindi solo in questa chiave negativa) (https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/17?seq=983, punto 4). Poi, io continuo a essere perplesso per il fatto che lì l'unico esempio venga da Nanni Balestrini, grandissimo scrittore ma anche grande sperimentatore e violatore di norme, e che le altre opere di consultazione siano appunto dizionari it-en, per i quali a voler pensare male si può insinuare il dubbio sul calco che menzionavo.

Comment: Figurati, ma io l'ho trovato anch in altri contesti, quello era il più autorevole, ma comunque a me suona familiare. E a me suon giusta la osservazione di Anna Bonvivicin , perché mi sembra che nell'uso comune spesso sia usato i frasi negative.

Comment: Sono d'ccordo su Balestrini, ma lì non mi sembra una sperimentazione, e io l'ho sempre sentito. Se posso dare un consiglio all'OP, se uno non è di madre lingua lasci stare verbi alternativi, si rischiano cose stiracchiate ed è inutile. 'Fare' uno scherzo va benissimo, in qualunque contesto, più formale o colloquiale.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Sono molto d'accordo su quest'ultimo punto, anche per i madrelingua. C'è un certo ritegno, forse di origine scolastica, a usare il verbo “fare”, che invece non ha mai fatto male a nessuno, mentre a volte si sfiora il ridicolo cercando di sostituirlo con “svolgere”, “eseguire” etc. (parlo in generale, non solo del caso presente).

Comment: Hai ragione! Aggiungo 'praticare lo sport', tipo 'pratico il tennis' nel colloquio, che fa drizzare i capelli in testa. Sembra , non so se ti ricordi Paolo Villaggio, "portatore sano di congiuntivi" (una delle battute più spiritose che ho mai sentito).